# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined on NgbTooltip - @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I get an error saying Cannot read property 'split' of undefined when hovering the tooltip created out of NgbTooltip from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap. I see the placement value is received as 'undefined' on debugging and when I checked html, the code seems good and I am passing the value for [placement] attribute.

Error in the console:

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54
next @ application_ref.js:348
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:236
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:338
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:169
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:420
error_handler.js:59 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:59
next @ application_ref.js:348
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:236
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:338
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:169
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:420
error_handler.js:60 TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Positioning.positionElements (positioning.js:83)
    at positionElements (positioning.js:129)
    at tooltip.js:47
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (async.js:105)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:236)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at EventEmitter.Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
    at EventEmitter.emit (async.js:79)
    at ng_zone.js:244
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:334)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:126)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (ng_zone.js:164)
    at NgZone.checkStable (ng_zone.js:244)
```

My HTML code:

```
<template #tipContent>{{licenorsTooltip}}</template>
  <button type="button" class="licensor-btn"  [placement]="bottom" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent" #t="ngbTooltip" triggers="manual" 
    (click)="toggleSelect()" on-mouseover='toolTipOver()' on-mouseleave="toolTipLeave()"> </button>
```

Please note the tooltip is working as expected and error is thrown only on the first instance of hovering. could someone say whats wrong with the code?

Comment: I got the error removed by using `placement` instead of `[placement]`.

Comment: `placement` should be `string`

Comment: Either use `placement="bottom"` or `[placement]="'bottom'"` or `bottom` should be `string` property in `[property]="bottom"`